# Run IE8 on Ubuntu/Linux

Tags: windows, linux, internet-explorer, ubuntu

My preferred area is in web applications. Currently my developing OS is Windows 7. But I like to work on Linux(Ubuntu). but still I have to stay with Windows as I have to test application in  Internet explore. I searched articles in internet how to run IE 8 on Ubuntu. Many articles were found and but some posts to those ways had said that they didn't work (some thing called `wine installer` had been used). Some articles said to install virtual machine-VMware or Sandbox..(which could waste time to me while testing..). I want to run single OS and installing virtual machines is not preferred for me.

I want your valuable experience about running application in IE8 on Ubuntu 12( or linux).Is it 100% possible to run IE 8 on Ubuntu 12 with no problem? or what can I do to test web pages in IE 8 on Ubuntu/Linux Thanks in advance.

Comment: The only real way to do this is to setup a virtual machine.  Personally, I like VirtualBox.  However, VMWare is also quite popular.

Comment: I'm a 100% Linux user (recently switched from Ubuntu 12.0 to ArchLinux). To test IE, I don't use Wine or something, but VirtualBox. I've done lots of research, and constructed a Virtual machine which is blazing fast. I've posted a detailed guide at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10541225.

Comment: @RobW. Thank you very much for your link and the great explanation on that answer. One question if you don't mind and not regarding this question. As a beginner to Linux, can I know why you moved to ArchLinux from Ubuntu ? Because I m to start with Ubuntu-Linux Mint. Is there a special reason ?

Comment: @AashMaharoon The final trigger for me to move to ArchLinux is that the Chromium "daily-builds" PPA isn't actively maintained any more. Ubuntu users are currently stuck at Chromium 18 (we're at 20 stable right now). I had to compile Chromium myself, which takes a while. ArchLinux is bleeding-edge: I can always have the last version of the software, if I wish. As a beginner, using Ubuntu isn't that bad.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to do this unless you run a [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/download/) or a similar program and even so, be prepared to see crashes and what not. The VM approach is the best advice, IMO.

Comment: Thanks Icarus. I saw in articles that some people had said many crashes with `WINE`.

Comment: Yeah, Wine has been in development for as far as I can remember but so few applications are well supported that is not very useful for anything that's not related to games (see here: http://appdb.winehq.org/ to see what I mean)

Comment: I wouldn't expect IE to run in WINE at all, and if it does, it's unlikely to behave identically.  Much of the functionality of IE is actually part of Windows rather than being part of the IE application itself.

Comment: Just for the record, Wine is not an emulator (as the name "Wine Is Not an Emulator" implies) but a compatibility layer.